# Free disk space on SQL without impacting application

Tags: sql-server, disk-space

We have 1 TB disk which is almost full(85%). We're going to free up disk space without any impact on application availability with below approach. Please suggest if this approach looks good or there is any other better approach?

1. Create new Drive(H) with new capacity
2. Create new APP_DB_NEW database
3. Create tables, stored procedures, indexes etc. in APP_DB_NEW database
4. Give all required access to APP_DB_NEW database similar to APP_DB database
5. Stop IIS
6. Rename APP_DB to APP_DB_ARCHIVE and then APP_DB_NEW to APP_DB
7. Start IIS

At #6 application will start writing data to new blank database. Also any idea how much time #6 take to complete. Every month around 200 GB data is being added in database.

We're also looking for suggestion to avoid step #5

Comment: Rather than copying the data between two databases during a downtime window, have you considered simply copying the data files to the new drive?

Comment: @AMtwo yes but that process( taking db offline, detach db, copying files to new drive and attach db) require 4-5 hours application downtime which is not acceptable due to application SLA so looking for different approach to avoid downtime. Please note we're not copying data in approach mentioned in question. New db comes with new blank mdf files

Comment: To clarify, you don't need the existing data? If so, why not just run a few `truncate` statements to clear down your existing database. Your application may or may not just handle that depending on what it caches from the DB on load - if it's cache is inconsistent with the DB then I would expect problems, but an app restart shouldn't take significant amounts of time. If you need the data, then just follow David Browne's  answer.

Comment: thank you @AndrewSayer for response and yes we need that data so we'll go approach mentioned in answer

Answer (score 1):

Just [add another data file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/add-data-or-log-files-to-a-database) to the database's primary filegroup on the new drive.  SQL Server will write a majority of new data to that file until the two files become equally full.

Comment: thank you @David this looks quick solution to get rid of disk space issue without impacting application. After adding new files we also want to get rid of old mdf files. How can we disassociate old mdf files. We need old mdf files for analysis stored data till date

Comment: Backup the database and restore it to a new drive, stop IIS and truncate the tables.
Or setup the new database, stop IIS, change the connection string to point to the new one and restart

Comment: thank you @Spörri but in this case there will be application downtime which we want to avoid( stop IIS ). that's why looking for any approach where there is no impact on application

Answer (score 0):

One option with almost no downtime:

- Mirror the drives using a Windows Dynamic Disk, where the second drive is larger than the original
- Wait for full synchronization
- Detach the original, and delete its volume marked `Missing`
- Extend the volume to fill the whole drive
- Ideally replace the original with a new drive of the same size as your other new one